# How can I find current username and system disk?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a simple console app, that just cleans `%temp%` files.
So, how can I find the username and system disk to input it in directory of temp files?

This is a string variable, where I plan to store the `%temp%` directory:

```
string tempDir = sysDisk << ":/Users/" << userName << "AppData/Local/Temp/"
```

Comment: Try `%username%`

Comment: Just read respective environmental variable (`std::getenv`).

Comment: You can use `%LocalAppData%` to get to the `appdata/local` folder for the current user.

Comment: A temp dir can be obtained with [`std::filesystem::temp_directory_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path)

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this all wrong.  You don't need to retrieve the system disk or username at all.  Especially since the location of the `%temp%` folder is **user-defined**, so there is no guarantee that it is even located at the path you are trying to create. And also that the location of Windows' `USERS` and `TEMP` folders have changed over time, and so may change again in the future.

The *correct* solution is to ask the OS exactly where the user's actual `%temp%` folder is currently located.

For instance, by using either:

- [`std::getenv()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv)

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
std::string tempDir = std::getenv("TEMP");
```

- [`std::filesystem::temp_directory_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path)

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
std::string tempDir = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path().string();
```

Or, using Win32 API functions:

- [`GetTempPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha)

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
char path[MAX_PATH] = {};
DWORD len = GetTempPath(path, MAX_PATH);
std::string tempDir(path, len);
```

- [`GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getenvironmentvariablea)

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
char path[MAX_PATH] = {};
DWORD len = GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", path, MAX_PATH);
std::string tempDir(path, len);
```

- [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa)

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
char path[MAX_PATH] = {};
DWORD len = ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%", path, MAX_PATH);
std::string tempDir(path, len-1);
// This would be useful when dealing with individual filenames, eg:
// ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%\filename.ext", path, MAX_PATH);
```